# Show hidden values in chrome

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

I was wondering if there is a way to show the values for the key variable?
There isn't a check for the answers, and I cannot for the life of me find out the answer. Please help:

```html
<form method="post" action="/webwork2//Section13.3/5/" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="problemMainForm" name="problemMainForm" onsubmit="submitAction()">
  <input type="hidden" name="user" value="name" id="hidden_user" />
  <input type="hidden" name="effectiveUser" value="name" id="hidden_effectiveUser" />
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="ZHaiEU4qkcpMc1m2kBaYrMvbOo5TktAY" id="hidden_key" />
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You could view the source with inspect? Or convert all hidden fields to text

Comment: Convert all hidden field to text

Answer (score 6):

This simple **JavaScript** function makes visible all `hidden` inputs on the site:

```js
function showHiddenInputs() {
    inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input'));
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
        if (input.type === 'hidden')
            input.type = 'text';
})}

showHiddenInputs();
```

One-liner to the browser console:

```js
inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')); inputs.forEach((input) => { if (input.type === 'hidden') input.type = 'text'; })
```

If you wanna get value only from element with name "key", use this in console:

```js
document.getElementsByName('key')[0].value
```

You can use any other number instead of 0, if there are multiple elements with name "key" or you can use this loop:

```js
elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByName('lsd'));
elements.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.type === 'hidden')
        console.log(element.value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('hidden_key').value);
console.log(document.getElementsByName('key')[0].value);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/webwork2//Section13.3/5/" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="problemMainForm" name="problemMainForm" onsubmit="submitAction()">
  <input type="hidden" name="user" value="name" id="hidden_user" />
  <input type="hidden" name="effectiveUser" value="name" id="hidden_effectiveUser" />
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="ZHaiEU4qkcpMc1m2kBaYrMvbOo5TktAY" id="hidden_key" />
</form>
```